# Informatica Powercentre not able to read messages from Kafka source topic. how to read Json message from Kafka topic in informatica powercentre?

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have a simple workflow where in the source is kafka topic and target is flat file. it is a one-one mapping. I have imported the kafka topic and created mapping as follows.

[image: mapping image]

[image: session config for Source qualifier]

I have imported the Kafka Topic using powerexchange for Kafka source in source analyzer. I have created a json file with all the fields and used for importing the kafka source. I am wondering if my source imported is in correct format like the fields as job is succeeded but could not pick any message.

sample topic message::

```
`{

  "metadata": {

    "correlationId": "3452658399_20231011063145338354-232",

    "eventType": "FTAEventPublisher",

    "processDateTimeUTC": "2023-10-12T12:56:26.1441781Z",

    "eventID": "a0ec992a-cf7c-4d86-bb84-428055bb2506",

    "keyIdentifiers": {

      "AccountID": "34526589",

      "Identifier": "NONCHMA"

    }

  },

  "data": {

    "accountId": 34526589,

    "salesrep": {

      "referenceData": {

        "name": "V, SUMAN",

        "email": null,

        "roleName": " Data Protection Solutions Sales Engineer",

        "NT_login": null

      },

      "badgeID": 580112,

      "primaryAssignee": "N",

      "roleID": 21966,

      "regionalStartDate": "1/29/2022 12:48:38 PM",

      "regionalEndDate": null,

      "accountOwner": "Y",

      "status": "A"

    }

  }

}
```

[Session logs click here to download](https://file.io/dXGIf8XqLcwX)

[json schema file used to import in informatica for source definition based on schema](https://file.io/yBJq1VfNiFkw)

I have executed the workflow to read message from kafka source however the workflow will run and succeeded there is no source data being read and processed to target. I am working on kafka for the first time. Kindly look into the mapping and source schema if i have done it right.

Comment: Please check if the Kafka topic has any messages. May be by the time you executed the workflow, messages would be cleared

Comment: @JimMacaulayKafka topic has message. Is this correct way of using Kafka source in informatica or do we need to create a single column as Json data and import as string the entire record?

Comment: can you show session config for source qualifier? I'd need to see the properties

Comment: @MaciejgI have posted the session config for source qualifier in the post. can you check?

Comment: Any update on the above. i have attached the session logs and also the json schema file used to import source definition